# Proof of Cayley's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

This question relates to the link:
[Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem)

The way I reasoned in showing the map T is a Homomorphism is as follows:

> Definition:
>
> A Homomorphism $\phi: \left ( G,\ast \right ) \rightarrow  \left ( H,\cdot  \right )$ preserves group operation.
>
> This is,
> $\forall g, h \in G $, $\left ( g \ast h \right )\phi=\left ( g \right )\phi \cdot \left ( h \right )\phi$

Suppose $g, h \in G.$

$$\begin{align}
\left ( x \right )\left(f_{g} \ast f_{h}\right)&=\left ( \left ( x \right )f_{g} \right ) f_{h} \\
&=\left ( g \ast x \right )f_{h} \\
&=h \ast \left ( g \ast x \right ) \\
&=\left ( h \ast g \right ) \ast x \\
&=\left ( x \right )f_{g} \ast f_{h} \\
&=\left ( g \right )T\cdot\left ( h \right )T.
\end{align}$$

As can be seen, it is different to the one provided by wiki. Is my proof valid?

Comment: It looks pretty much the same as the one in your link. But why are you writing your functions on the right instead of the left ? Also, what is the significance of the ">" in your defn of the homomorphism ? It doesn't seem to appear anywhere in your proof.

Comment: @rt6 I don't know the OP's reasons, but sometimes I like writing functions on the right because then composition has the nice property that $f \circ g$ means "$f$, then $g$", instead of the reverse.

Comment: But, I have to say, writing functions on the right is weird in this context when the function is denoting left multiplication...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is fine, except you're missing $(x)(g\ast h)T$ at the beginning and the last line should be $(x)((g)T\cdot (h)T)$

Using the arguments of the functions on the left is a little quaint; however, the notation is used in semigroup theory a lot, so I guess it's fine too.